# How to superimpose a layout on a image in ARcore?

Tags: java, android, augmented-reality, arcore, sceneform

I have tried my best to superimpose a layout on a image target. The layout is shown vertical to the target image but i want the layout to perfectly superimpose the target image. I have tried to rotate the layout using anchor nodes but no success. Please help me in this problem as i am very new to the arcore and sceneform.
This is my code snippet that i have tried

```
private void createViewRenderable(Anchor anchor, float extentX, float extentZ, List<Integer> image_list) {
    ViewRenderable
            .builder()
            .setView(this, R.layout.test)
            .build()
            .thenAccept(viewRenderable -> {
                addToScene(viewRenderable, anchor, image_list);
                renderable = viewRenderable;
            });

    anchorNode = new AnchorNode(anchor);

    // Create the transformable andy and add it to the anchor.
    // TransformableNode node = new TransformableNode(arFragment.getTransformationSystem());

    //set rotation in direction (x,y,z) in degrees 90

    texture.getSurfaceTexture().setOnFrameAvailableListener(surfaceTexture -> {
        anchorNode.setParent(arFragment.getArSceneView().getScene());
        Vector3 vector3 = new Vector3(0f, 0f, extentZ / 2);

        anchorNode.setLocalPosition(vector3);
        anchorNode.setLocalRotation(Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(1.0f, 0f, 0f), -90f));
        anchorNode.setLocalScale(new Vector3(extentX, extentZ, 0f));
        anchorNode.setRenderable(renderable);
        texture.getSurfaceTexture().setOnFrameAvailableListener(null);
        anchorNode.setWorldScale(new Vector3(extentX, 1f, extentZ));

        scene.addChild(anchorNode);
    });
```

What do i want to achieve?
I want to display all the images in a viewpager adapter, that code is working just fine but only problem is that the following layout (R.layout.test) - containing viewpager is vertical to target image. See below
[image]

Answer (score 0):

In your code:

```
anchorNode.setLocalRotation(Quaternion.axisAngle(new Vector3(1.0f, 0f, 0f), -90f));
```

You're setting the local rotation of the x axis by -90 degrees. Try commenting out this line or setting it to different values.

Comment: Nope this does not fix my problem